# Property attribute depending on Windows version

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-8, character-encoding, propertygrid

I have a bit strange problem.

WinForms in Win8 have some bug about Encoding 1252 (confirmed).

I have usercontrol with a public property of Encoding class (user can choose encoding in design-time).

Currently, I want to hide that property from property grid when user uses my control's dll in Win8 environment.

I want to base on : [Operating System Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

and want to hide property by DesignerVisibility attribute.

So my question is : How to hide a property when I look for Windows's version by Environment.OSVersion ?

PS Idea may looks ugly, i can use another classes or anything you can propose, i just need to hide this property in property grid in case of Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, before showing the property grid object:

```
if (IsWindows8()
{
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Encoding), new BrowsableAttribute(false));
}
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = myObject;
```